# Service getting called multiple times?

Tags: android, service

I am developing an application where I am running  some background operations and displaying notification to the user when certain condition meets .When the user clicks on the notification it should take him to the main activity , with out restarting the service .

My problem is when I am clicking the  notification it takes me to the  main activity and starting my service again.I dont want to restart my service again .How can I achieve this .

I have used the following code to check weather a service running or not lease look at it

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceName,Context context){
boolean serviceRunning = false;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> l = am.getRunningServices(50);
Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> i = l.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo) i
            .next();

    if(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceName)){
        serviceRunning = true;
    }
}
return serviceRunning;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have used this piece of code and it's working fine :)

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
    {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) 
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check `getIntent()` on the activity and put some extra on the intent bundle of the notification that you check to start or not the service.

Note:

if a service is already running, it is not restarted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally I have rectified my code.as follows 


private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {

        if ("com.example.sevicedemosolution.Myservice".equals(service.service.getClassName().toString())) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```